# Testing an async helper function in a fastapi project with beanie

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI for my server and I've added a feature that uses background tasks for doing some processing after the request was served.

I've written alot of tests for my routes but I'm finding it hard to write tests for my background task. I've found [this](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1205) which shows how to stub out the background task and make sure it is called.

But I want to test the background task itself, its logic and I cant seem to find a way of doing this.

I'm using beanie, and this is a simple version of the function I'm trying to test

```
async def _create_product(
    plan: Plan, 
    api_key: str,
    create_stripe_product: Callable[[str, str], stripe.Product]
) -> FixedProduct:
    stripe_product = create_stripe_product(api_key)

    product = Product(
        stripe_id=stripe_product.id,
        plan=plan
    )

    return await product.save()
```

`create_stripe_product` is just a function that wraps the use of stripe api.

`Plan` and `Product` are both beanie documents and the function itself is async and needs beanie to be initialized, any tips on how to approach this?